# C++ Access violation reading location when using strcpy

Tags: c++, file, io

**The command to compile in Ubuntu Terminal is `g++ scrap.c -std=c++11`**

I looked at several other questions with the same error but none use `strcat` which is where the exception occurs for me.

I am trying to copy all chars from `test1` into `temp[]` in chunks of 512 chars at a time, but I am getting an exception `Access violation reading location 0x...`.

Another thing I'm trying to do is load temp into an item of `fileArray[]` but the `strcpy` at the bottom of my code is giving me `no suitable conversion from str to "char *" exists`.

I tried hard to give a "complete, minimal, verifiable example" since admins seem to be pushing that really hard right now; please let me know if I did it right here. You should just be able to copy my code and compile it with g++ to check it.

**scrap.c (Updated):**

```
//#include <stdafx.h>
//#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>  /* defines FILENAME_MAX */
#include <assert.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
//#include <filesystem>
#include <experimental/filesystem>
#include "dirent.h"
//#include <direct.h>
using namespace std;


int main() {
    string test1 = "This is test1.txt...This is test1.txt...";
    std::vector<std::string> fileArray[10];

    string temp = "";

    for (int a = 0; a < 10; a++) {
        int block = 512 * a;
        int currentBlockPosition = 0;
        while (currentBlockPosition < 512 && (currentBlockPosition + block) < test1.size()) {
                    temp += test1.at(block + currentBlockPosition);
                    cout << "block + currentBlockPos: " << block + currentBlockPosition << endl;
                    cout << "current char: " << test1.at(block + currentBlockPosition) << endl;
                    currentBlockPosition++;
            }
            temp = "";
            cout << "temp: " << temp << endl;
            cout << "a: " << a << endl;
            //fileArray[a] =  temp; // no operator "=" matches these operands    ... operand types are: std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string>> = std::string
    }
}
```

Comment: temp is an array of one `char`, so writing to a string with length one or more (plus the terminating `'\0'`) using `strcat(temp, ...)` gives undefined behavior.    No need to use `strcpy()` to copy to a `std::string` - simple assignment will do.

Comment: `char temp[] = "";` - this declares a `char` array containing exactly one character, the terminating `'\0'`. No more, no less. Your subsequent attempt to `strcat()` anything other than an empty string here will be doomed to failure, because this will end up corrupting innocent memory, that violated no law, and just minded its own business, wishing just to be left alone. Please respect the innocent memory's wishes, and don't corrupt it.

Comment: javascript tag? why?

Comment: Thanks everyone, a string would make more sense. I changed temp to a string but now the strcat statement is not allowing me to concatenate a char to a string. I updated my code in the question

Comment: Can whoever downvoted my question tell me why they did so. I put in effort on this question to follow the guidelines

Comment: Not a downvoter, but to have a [mcve] you almost always need to have a runnable program or a program that would be runnable if not for the compiler error you're looking to have resolved. This is incomplete.

Comment: How is it incomplete? The code I posted is runnable

Comment: Also, I'm getting error `no operand '=' matches these opeands: string vector/allocator, string` when trying `fileArray[a] =  temp;` at the bottom.

Comment: Your last two comments cannot both be logically true. If the code "is runnable", you would not get this compilation error. You have to compile the code succesfully in order to be able to run it.

Comment: So what am I doing wrong @SamVarshavchik? My code is runnable EXCEPT for the problem that I'm currently facing

Comment: "Runnable"  means that we the prospective helpers can cut the code out of your question, paste it into an IDE editor, compile it and run it.  So make that happen.

Comment: The title is obsolete.

Comment: @JiveDadson Oh I see, thanks. I commented out the syntax error so the code is now runnable. I have updated the code in the question. I solved the out of bounds error by adding the extra condition in the while(). Now the only problem I have is assigning `fileArray[a] = temp;` at the bottom. I listed the error in the comment.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.

The access violation error had to do with me using a `char []` instead of a `string`.

Using `fileArray->push_back(temp);` turned out to be the proper syntax instead of `fileArray[a] = temp`.

Also, I had to add in the second condition in the `while()` to avoid the out of bounds error.